# Five Category Ordered Probit Log Likelihood Function in R Help : Survey Data Research

Tags: r, survey

I am currently working with some survey data that has a 5 category scale. I have used a ML method before for a 4 category scale and I am trying to adapt the code for the new survey in R.

The original code that worked was:

```
#Load Data
mathcomp <- read.csv("RRawComposite11.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
attach(mathcomp)

#Ordered Probit Liklihood
llk.oprobit4 <- function(param, x, y) {

 os <- rep(1, nrow(x))

  x <- cbind(os, x)  

  b <- param[1:ncol(x)]

  t2 <- param[(ncol(x)+1)]

  t3 <- param[(ncol(x)+2)]

  xb <- x%*%b

  p1 <- log(pnorm(-xb))

  if (t2<=0)  p2 <- -(abs(t2)*10000)

  else p2 <- log(pnorm(t2-xb)-pnorm(-xb))

  if (t3<=t2) p3 <- -((t2-t3)*10000)

  else p3 <- log(pnorm(t3-xb)-pnorm(t2-xb))   

  p4 <- log(1-pnorm(t3-xb))

  -sum(cbind(y==1,y==2,y==3,y==4) * cbind(p1,p2,p3,p4))
}
```

The modified code I am trying to use is:

```
llk.oprobit5 <- function(param, x, y) {

 os <- rep(1, nrow(x))

  x <- cbind(os, x)  

  b <- param[1:ncol(x)]

  t2 <- param[(ncol(x)+1)]

  t3 <- param[(ncol(x)+2)]

  t4 <- param[(ncol(x)+3)]

 xb <- x%*%b

  p1 <- log(pnorm(-xb))

  if (t2<=0)  p2 <- -(abs(t2)*10000)

else p2 <- log(pnorm(t2-xb)-pnorm(-xb))

  if (t3<=t2) p3 <- -((t2-t3)*10000)

else p3 <- log(pnorm(t3-xb)-pnorm(t2-xb))  

  if (t4<=t3) p4 <- -((t3-t4)*10000)  

else p4 <- log(pnorm(t4-xb)-pnorm(t3-xb)) 

  p5 <- log(1-pnorm(t4-xb))

-sum(cbind(y==1,y==2,y==3,y==4,y==5) * cbind(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5))
}
```

I am getting an error message saying:

> Error in if (t4 <= t3) p4 <- -((t3 - t4) * 10000) else p4 <-
>   log(pnorm(t4 -  :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Does anyone know how to fix the likelihood function to make this work? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the `param` argument to`llk.oprobit5(...)` have `ncol(x) + 3` elements? Otherwise t4=NA.